# Add break point in ruby mine if application is running using docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, dockerfile, rubymine

Here is docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - RUBYOPT=-rdebug
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: debug-rails
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c "bundle install && rails server -b 0.0.0.0"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: debug-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myappuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myapppassword
      POSTGRES_DB: myappdb
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

and below is my docker file

```
# Use the official Ruby image
FROM ruby:2.7.5

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    nodejs \
    yarn

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock into the container
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

# Install gems
RUN bundle install
RUN gem install ruby-debug-ide debase
RUN gem install docker-api



# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Start the application
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Can some one help me with steps how to connect with docker break point?

I am trying to add break point like debugger we normally add in ruby mine.

Comment: Not exactly on point answer, but did you try an alternative approach like using a debugging library like `pry`?

Answer (score 0):

In your *docker-compose.yml* try to comment out the following lines:

```
environment:
      - RUBYOPT=-rdebug
```

and

```
command: bash -c “bundle install && rails server -b 0.0.0.0”
```

If you still experiencing the problem, please add more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try. Add it to docker compose file

```
web:
    ....
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

You can access web container `docker exec -it debug-rails /bin/bash` when put `debugger`